# Write and debug autokey script in pycharm

Tags: debugging, ide, pycharm, autokey

It's definitely difficult to write and debug [autokey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey) scripts in it's GUI window. I know that you can run a script using `autokey-run --script {script-name}`.

But is it possible to use `autokey` module explicitly in a `.py` file and write a standalone script and run it independently? That way it would be possible to take advantage of all IDE features like **autocompletion**, **line-by-line debugging**, seeing **stacktrace in case of exception** when writing a script.

Comment: you can write some simple features like this yourself. E.g. the Ctrl + G (goto Line) shortcut [Helper_linesDown.py](https://gist.github.com/sl5net/d0390970d43ccf10ab47cf2c70bacbe9)

Comment: this also helps a little bit: `popupNotify_howItWorks(text)`, `beeps(duration=.1, freq=2000, loops=1)`  https://gist.github.com/a6576f9dec0fd254b8a96c4b3a9cf1ba `import os,  subprocess`